# Get HTTP or HTTPS from Current URL

Tags: java, jsp

I simply want to get whether the current URL is under HTTP or HTTPS.  The issue is we have a number of self-signed certificates in our testing environments so validating the cert probabluy isn't an option.  I've tried the following, but thry don't appear to work in all cases.

```
String protocol = request.getProtocol();
out.println(protocol); // prints out HTTP/1.1 on self signed servers

Boolean secure = ((HttpServletRequest)pageContext.getRequest()).isSecure();
if (secure) {
  out.println("secure")
} else {
  out.println("not secure")  // always fails
}
```

I suppose I could use getRequest and search the string for "https" - but I'm assuming there's a truly supported way of doing this.

Comment: [java ee doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#isSecure%28%29) says `isSecure()` returns a boolean indicating whether this request was made using a secure channel, such as HTTPS. It doesn't seem like it cares about self-signed certificates.

Comment: Just guessing, but have you tried this with real signed certificate? Maybe it returns false because self signed certs are not secure.

Comment: `isSecure` should work, but it depends on your environment as well, e.g. your HTTP reverse proxy configuration. Any HTTP server guarding your application server?

Answer (score 2):

It does not matter if self-signed or official certs are used. If SSL/TLS is NOT terminated at the deployment container 'isSecure()' will return 'false' by default.  However some deployment containers like Tomcat can be configured to return 'true' for 'isSecure()' call even if SSL/TLS is NOT terminated at the deployment container. E.g. this is helpful if SSL is terminated at a (hardware-)loadbalancer and 'sendRedirect()' is used with relative URL.